# love2d can't move rectangle using draw function

Tags: lua, love2d

```
function love.load()
    Player = {
            x = 1, 
            y = 1,
            w = 50,
            h = 50
    }

    Player.self = love.graphics.rectangle("fill", Player.x, Player.y, Player.w, Player.h)    
end


function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(Player.self, Player.x, Player.y) --15 line
end
```

I am having some issue here could help me I started love2d not long time ago so i am trying to figure it out.

main.lua:15: bad argument #1 to 'draw' (Drawable expected, got nil)

Comment: I figure it out sorry.

https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:Gridlocked_Player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @Quiloos39 figured it out by themself, for future reference:

It's because `love.graphics.rectangle` does not return anything - it just draws a rectangle at the specified coordinates. `love.graphics.draw` requires a `Drawable` as its first parameter. `Drawable`s are somewhat more complex than rectangles: They can be created using `love.graphics.newSomething` where `Something` can be any of the following:

- [Canvas](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newCanvas)
- [Framebuffer](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newFramebuffer) (Removed in 0.8.0)
- [Image](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newImage)
- [Mesh](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newMesh)
- [ParticleSystem](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newParticleSystem)
- [SpriteBatch](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newSpriteBatch)
- [Text](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newText)
- [Video](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newVideo)

For more info on `Drawable`s, see [Drawable in the love2d wiki](https://love2d.org/wiki/Drawable).

---

In order to just draw a rectangle at the player's current position, use:

```
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", Player.x, Player.y, Player.w, Player.h)
end
```

There is no need to call `love.graphics.rectangle` in `love.load` whatsoever, as it will neither draw nor return anything. As soon as you're planning to use an image for the player, however, it would be wise to load the image up front in `love.load` and use it in love.draw, like so:

```
function love.load()
    Player = { 
        x = 1, 
        y = 1, 
        w = 50, 
        h = 50, 
        image = love.graphics.newImage("img/player.png")
    }
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(Player.image, Player.x, Player.y)
end
```